# Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-ec2

[image]

we are using ec2 instance and trying to run Samplepage.php given in the blog https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html . There was no my.cnf file so we created it but it didnt worked.

Comment: I googled the error and found: https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/13756#issuecomment-520638540

Comment: It appears to be a conflict between the version of PHP / MySQL that you are running.

Comment: Yes, I already saw that but I don't know how to fix this. As it is aws EC2 instance I am not sure where to make changes.